# nginx redirect all urls to index.html

Tags: reactjs, redirect, nginx, react-router

I am trying to configure nginx server according to following guide: https://gkedge.gitbooks.io/react-router-in-the-real/content/nginx.html

But looks like it doesn't work, I am trying to use with my docker image of nginx. So,

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM nginx:1.11.5

COPY /dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY /vhosts.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/vhosts.conf
```

**vhosts.conf:**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name /usr/share/nginx/html;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;      

    location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
      expires -1;
      # access_log logs/static.log; # I don't usually include a static log
    }

    location ~* \.(?:css|js|json)$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      expires 1y;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Any route containing a file extension (e.g. /devicesfile.js)
    location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
    }

    # Any route that doesn't have a file extension (e.g. /devices)
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Trying to open a page that doesn't exists.

`GET localhost/somestupidrandomurl`

**nginx error log:**

`[error] 7#7: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/somestupidrandomurl" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /somestupidrandomurl HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After a deep search, I realize that the thing is, there is one more default.conf file at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` path and that config overwrites my config.

I simply replace the Dockerfile line 3 as

`COPY /vhosts.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` and works like a magic.